# Accordion icon change on click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, accordion

My current accordion opens and closes fine and is working as I'd like, however the icons do not change properly when closing tabs.

Is there away to have the icons change to match the tabs status even if another tab is opened, closing the previous tab?

essentially the icon should show a minus when its open and a plus when its closed, so when an open tab is clicked it changes...

here is a JS Fiddle to hopefully make more sense of it all...https://jsfiddle.net/wf2goy8s/4/

here is my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var main_blc = $('.main-blc-accord');
    main_blc.find('dd').hide();
    main_blc.find('dd').prev().addClass('plus')
    main_blc.find('dd').first().prev().removeClass('plus');
    main_blc.find('dd').first().show();

    main_blc.find('dt').on('click', function(event) { 
        var dd=$(this).next('dd');
        main_blc.find('dd').not(dd).slideUp('slow');        
        dd.slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('plus');    
    });

    $('.mobile-btn-menu').find('span').on('click', function(event) {
            $(this).parent().next('.footer-menu').toggleClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the CSS of `plus` ?

Comment: it uses an image called "sprite" and moves the layout to display it

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS along these lines.  I added this to your fiddle and it worked, except the .plus class is not initially applied, but you can work that out.

```
.plus h3:before {
    content: "+ ";
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry I've just updated my js fiddle with the css i am currently using with the site https://jsfiddle.net/wf2goy8s/4/

Comment: Thanks, I posted another suggestion as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/30u0npss/3/

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt><span>Title 1</span><i class="plus"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">Content 1</dd>
    <dt><span>Title 2</span><i class="plus"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">Content 2</dd>
    <dt><span>Title 3</span><i class="plus"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">Content 3</dd>
</dl>
jQuery('.accordion dt').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').find('i').toggleClass('plus minus')
           .closest('dt').siblings('dt')
           .removeClass('active').find('i').removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');

          jQuery(this).next('.accordion_content').slideToggle().siblings('.accordion_content').slideUp();


});

jQuery('.accordion_content').hide();
.plus:before{
   content:"+";
}
.minus:before{
   content:"-";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track if it is expanding, then toggle the plus for all nodes, and finally if it was expanding, handle appropriately:

```
main_blc.find('dt').on('click', function(event) { 
    var expanding = false
    if ($(this).attr('class')==='plus')
        expanding = true
    main_blc.find('dt').addClass('plus');
    var dd=$(this).next('dd');
    main_blc.find('dd').not(dd).slideUp('slow');        
    dd.slideToggle();
    if (expanding)
        $(this).removeClass('plus')
});
```